# SEO: Single URL rewrite from one app to another

Tags: seo, nginx

I have two web applications running on two different servers.  I want one, example.com/hello, to redirect to the second, hello.com.  But I want both to contribute to each other's SEO ranking.  What is the best way to accomplish this primarily for google search and for other search engines?

I currently do a rewrite with permanent from example.com/hello to hello.com using nginx.

Comment: If both URLs pull up the same website than you have only one app to promote.

Comment: To clarify, example.com would be a separate app hosted on a different server, and only the single url example.com/hello would redirect to hello.com.  I would like these two sites to promote each other.  Do you have any advice on how best to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than use redirects to cross-promote your sites, you should just be linking the pages on on app to the other.    If users of `hello.com` would find `example.com` useful, put  a blurb about `example.com` on `hello.com` along with a link so that users can get from one to another.  Search engines will see this link as well.

Comment: Thank you for the answer!  Would you say it's better than doing a location redirect with nginx?

Comment: Unless you are currently serving the same content various URLs on both sites, a redirect is not going to accomplish anything.

Comment: I am!  So, I have two separate web applications.  I want each of them to promote the other.  Ex: on one url of application A, example.com/theothersite, it redirects to application B, theothersite.com.  I want this to happen so users of application A can find application B, and if someone searches for application B on google, it promotes application A.  Is a location rewrite good for this?  If not, what is?

Comment: You certainly don't want the same content served at different URLs.  Put in redirects to prevent duplicate content.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not very familiar with SEO.  Why is serving the same content at different URLs bad?

Comment: See: [What is duplicate content and how can I avoid being penalized for it on my site?](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/35652/what-is-duplicate-content-and-how-can-i-avoid-being-penalized-for-it-on-my-site)

Comment: Thank you for sharing your knowledge!  You've been incredibly helpful!